# How do I exit from an Ubuntu Bash that I started in Windows 10 Home, using Docker toolbox?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am setting up Docker. I have already run the basic command to see if it is up and running and then I tried another command:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Which enabled an Ubuntu Bash inside the Docker quick-start terminal.

I am trying to understand the command, what it does and how to end the Ubuntu Bash without restarting the Docker quick-start terminal.

```
    dell@DESKTOP-BCT4208 MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
     $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
     Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
     latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
     35c102085707: Pull complete
     251f5509d51d: Pull complete
     8e829fe70a46: Pull complete
     6001e1789921: Pull complete
     Digest: 
     sha256:d1d454df0f579c6be4d8161d227462d69e163a8ff9d20a847533989cf0c94d90
     Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
     root@ddabb25c2a2f:/#      //ubuntu bash started
```

Comment: `exit`? Ctrl+d?

Comment: ‘*I am trying to understand the command*’ [`man docker-run`](https://www.mankier.com/1/docker-run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Detached Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029680/docker-detached-mode)

Answer (score 1):

to do that you must start your container with `-d` to run in background:

```
docker run -itd ubuntu bash
```

then you can savely type `exit` or `contol-d` without killing the `container`

Comment: -d is detached mode, that means you can't see log in terminal  https://guide.freecodecamp.org/docker/docker-detached-mode/

Comment: I am agree with your answer, i just want to put extra details that's it

Comment: Thanks, that really helps in understanding the commands as well as solve my query.