# Script with a docker run command is not stopping on sigint or sigterm

Tags: linux, docker, shell, jenkins, unix

I have a script which contains a docker run command to run some arbitrary containers including certain tests on **Jenkins**.

The problem is that the script is executing further if sigint is ran and not even stopping on sigterm.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function test (){
# Sample script to run a docker container
    docker run httpd:latest
    echo test failed
}

test
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Dec 01 06:10:51.034719 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140008420530048] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 01 06:10:51.034842 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140008420530048] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
^C[Fri Dec 01 06:10:51.611085 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140008420530048] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
test failed # echo command executed
```

I want the script to stop all the containers and abort the script execution to prevent any further commands execution in the function including further docker run calls

I checked with trap command but it is also not working with sigterm.

Any idea why is it not working and how to fix it?

This is working as expected

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function test (){
    sleep 10
    echo test failed
}

test
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
^C⏎
```

Comment: Use `docker stop` in your signal handler

Comment: doesn't work up till that point without stopping the container externally.

Comment: #1 `echo test failed` is not printed? #2 Do you need start and stop the container `httpd`? #3 How are you executing the script with jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script and as you said, it never ends.

The reason is due to you are running in foreground mode. I mean the process is attached to the cli and no other commands will be executed.

This is a unix concept, not a docker thing. Check the references at the bottom.

To fix it, use the -d (which means detached mode) and also assign it a name to stop or delete it after:

```
docker run -d --name httpd_test httpd:latest
```

I modified your script

```
#!/bin/bash

function test () {
    docker run -d --name httpd_test httpd:latest
    echo "run tests"
    docker stop httpd_test
    echo "container stopped"
}

docker -v
test
```

And running with jenkins

[image]

the script ends as expected:

[image]

More details here:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground
- [Docker Detached Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029680/docker-detached-mode)
- https://linuxhandbook.com/run-process-background/
- https://everythingdevops.dev/linux-background-and-foreground-process-management/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed. Can you confirm is there a way if I can retain the output of the docker container output in jenkins task

Comment: ... That was not the question. What do you mean by retain? Do you want to query some values from inside of your container?

Comment: I intend to run integration tests on Jenkins.  So the output for showing the coverage and successful test cases is necessary. I might update the question to retain the same.

Comment: If the coverage is sent to the stdout (console) of container, you can get it with `docker logs <container_name>`